# Суффиксы в слове «пловец»

Tags: морфемный-разбор

В слове выделяется суффикс -в-, но почему, откуда он взялся? Почему корень не -плов-? Сравним с ковка — корень -ков-, кров — корень -кров-, слово — -слов-, клёв — -клёв-.

Comment: _Nadezhda: В слове [пловец]выделяется суффикс -в-…_ === Кем выделяется? Я, к примеру, не выделяю . Ефремова с Кузнецовой не выделяют, Панов с Текучевым не выделяют, Потиха не выделяет, Баранов не выделяет (это всё авторы словарей)…  Да и Тихонов не выделяет.  А кто выделяет-то?

Comment: Тихонов выделяет! Оттуда и начались мои сомнения и размышления.

Comment: _Nadezhda: Тихонов выделяет! Оттуда и начались мои сомнения и размышления._ === Нет, по Тихонову «-в-» в слове  _пловец_  – интерфикс (такой же, как, к примеру, в слове _пе/в/ец_). При упрощённом морфемном анализе этот интерфикс присоединяется к корню. Вот как членит на морфемы слово _пловец_ Тихонов в своём «Словаре-справочнике по русскому языку» (1997 г.): _плов/ец/_.

Comment: Спасибо! Я не знала, что при упрощенном морфемном анализе интерфикс присоединяется к корню. Это новая для меня информация, и важная.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Это продолжение первого ответа, поэтому кому интересно, начинайте читать с первого ответа, чтоб было понятно о чём речь.*

---

### Ответ на комментарии

> *Прошу прощения, у меня опять появился вопрос. А почему же тогда в словах "плыву, плывет, плывущий" тоже есть суффикс "в"? Тут уже другая
> причина должна быть, вероятно. Продаю, продающий… там -j- .*

> *С пловцом-то я разобралась, но теперь меня интересует другой вопрос.) На всякий случай галочку убрала, вдруг кто-то еще что-то знает по
> этому поводу. Может быть, в формах глагола "плыть" -в- взялось именно
> из -у- для устранения зияния гласных. Но тогда он должен, наверное,
> попадать в корень. Есть еще похожее слово "слывёт".*

---

*Я когда прочитал второй комментарий, уже почти дописал этот второй ответ. Но тут есть, то что подходит и под второй комментарий кроме «зияния гласных».*

---

По поводу: *плыть – плыву, плывет, плывущий*.

Существует такая вещь, как альтернация или чередование:

> **альтернация**
> лингв. последовательная мена гласных или согласных в определённых позициях или в определённых морфемах; чередование *[[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)]*

Может быть так, что в «плыть — плыву», имеет место чередование в корне, а не добавление суффикса -в-.

Это слово можно найти в книге *Русская грамматика, том I. Фонетика. Фонология. Ударение. Интонация. Введение в морфемику. Словообразование. Морфология. Н. Ю. ШВЕДОВА (главный редактор).*

Сокращённая цитата, многоточиями обозначены пропуски, слово «плыть» я выделил жирным, и рядом с ним есть «слыть», о котором вы спрашивали:

> **АЛЬТЕРНАЦИОННЫЕ РЯДЫ ФОНЕМ В ГЛАГОЛЬНЫХ ФОРМАХ**
>
> **АЛЬТЕРНАЦИОННЫЕ РЯДЫ СОГЛАСНЫХ ФОНЕМ**
>
> § 1596. В глагольном словоизменении представлены альтернационные ряды
> фонем, составляющие четыре группы. 
> …
>  **Четвертая группа альтернац. рядов согласных фонем** 
>  § 1601. В четвертую группу входят десять альтернац. рядов согласных фонем: |д —
> д’|, |т — т’|, |з — з’|, |с — с’|, |в — в’|, |к — к’|, |н — н’|, |л —
> л’|, |р — р’|, |м — м’|. 
>  …
> 5. Альтернац. ряд |в — в’| — в гл. кл. V
>  …
>  2 (соотн. основ 4): *жить, **плыть**, слыть:
>  жить, жи|в|ут — жи|в’|ёшь, жи|в’|ёт, жи|в’|ём, жи|в’|ёте; жи|в’|и(те), жи|в’|я.*

---

Я так понимаю, что тут речь идёт о чередовании согласных в корне слова. Похожая ситуация с примером: жить, живут — живёшь, живёт, живём, живёте; живи(те), живя.

*жить – живут

плыть – плывут*

В  статье [Чередование согласных в корне слова](https://obrazovaka.ru/russkiy-yazyk/cheredovanie-soglasnyh-v-korne-slova.html) на сайте [obrazovaka.ru](https://obrazovaka.ru/) сказано:

> В русском языке распространено такое явление, как чередование гласных
> в корне слова (вариантов чередования и корней с ним очень много), но
> встречаются и **корни с чередующимися согласными**. Есть несколько
> наиболее характерных разновидностей смены согласных и определенное
> объяснение данного явления в целом. Оно заслуживает отдельного
> внимания, поскольку такие чередования обязательно нужно запомнить.
>
> …
>
> На самом деле вариантов чередования согласных в корне очень много. Вот
> самые распространенные пары-тройки:
>
> ```
> г\ ж\ з – друг- дружить- друзья; т\ ч\ щ- свет- свеча- освещение; д\ ж\ жд- труд- тружусь- утруждать; ц\ч\к – лицо-личико-лик; с\ш\х – лес-леший, пахать-вспашка; щ\ск-ст – мощеный – мостить, лощеный – лоск; б\ бл- любовь- люблю; в\ вл- ловить- ловля; м\ мл- ломить- преломление; п\ пл- лупить- луплю; ф\ фл- графить- графлю.
> ```
>
> Объяснение этих процессов учеными-лингвистами достаточно простое:
> чередование образовалось в результате упрощения произношения, причем
> изначальный смысл звуков по мере протекания этого процесса
> утрачивался.

Таки образом, изменение согласной буквы с «т» на «в», можно объяснить упрощением произношения. У Шведовой четвёртая группа в которую входит «плыть» описана так:

> ч е т в е р т а я г р у п п а включает ряды «твердая
> переднеязычная смычная шумная — мягкая переднеязычная смычная шумная»,
> «твердая переднеязычная щелевая шумная — мягкая переднеязычная щелевая
> шумная», «твердая губная щелевая шумная — мягкая губная щелевая
> шумная», «твердая заднеязычная смычная — мягкая заднеязычная смычная»,
> «твердая сонорная — мягкая сонорная» (например, |д — д’|, |з — з’|, |в
> — в’|, |к — к’|, |н — н’|).

Однако удобство произношения может быть не единственным объяснением.

Из той же статьи [Чередование согласных в корне слова](https://obrazovaka.ru/russkiy-yazyk/cheredovanie-soglasnyh-v-korne-slova.html) с сайта [obrazovaka.ru](https://obrazovaka.ru/):

> В ученой среде бытует несколько ироническое выражение, которое звучит
> как “так сложилось исторически”. Оно объясняет многие непонятные
> явления в русском языке, в том числе и чередование согласных в корне.
> На самом деле такое объяснение имеет смысл – за каждой парой или
> тройкой чередующихся согласных в корне стоит длительный процесс
> языковых перемен.

Если посмотреть этимологиюслова «плыть» в этимологическом словаре Семёнова А. В.:

> **Плыть.** Древнерусское — плоути (плыть). Слово «плыть» широко применяется в русском языке с середины XI в. Первоначально это слово
> значило путешествовать по воде (на лодке, плоту, корабле). Форма
> «плыву» появилась в XVII–XVIII вв. Интересно, что исследователи
> предполагают родство глагола «плыть» с латинским словом pluit (идет
> дождь, дождит) и с немецким flut (дождь, поток воды). Родственным
> является: Литовское — ploviau (полоскаю, стираю). Производные:
> плавать, плыву, плывун.

Можно предположить, что изначально было, что-то вроде «плоути», а потом из-за
упрощения произношения (для удобства) инфинитив превратился в «плыть»
(пропало «у»), а, например, первое лицо настоящего времени превратилось «плыву»
(пропало «т», а «у» преобразовалось в «в» — это близкие звуки).

---

Для сравнения в латинском языке буква «V» использовалась вместо «U»:

> Непосредственно в классическом латинском языке, откуда буква V перешла
> в остальные языки, она использовалась также в качестве современной
> буквы U. В позднем латинском эти две буквы разделились для большего
> удобства, однако при написании слов заглавными буквами до сих пор
> изредка вместо U могут использовать V — например, в латинской
> Википедии. *[[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/V)]*

На латыни вода, например, «aq**u**a» («ак**у**а»), а говорят по-русски «ак**в**а». Таким образом, «у» вполне могла трактоваться к «в» и наоборот. А если это слово заимствованное то тем более.

Шанский в своем этимологическом словаре пишет, что «плыть» «общеслав. индоевроп. характера» и связывает его с «ср. др.-инд. plávatē». А в «plávatē», как видно, буква «v»:

> Плыть. Общеслав. индоевроп. характера (ср. др.-инд. plávatē «плывет»,
> лат. pluit «идет дождь», греч. pleō «плыву на судне» и т. д.).
>
> *[Этимологический словарь Шанского Н. М.]*

---

**Как вывод:**
Я думаю, что в *«плыть» — «плыву»*, имеет место не суффикс -в-, а чередование согласной в корне.

---

**Дополнение**

В книге *Грамматика русского языка. Том 1. Фонетика и морфология. В.В. Виноградов, Е.С. Истрина, С. Г. Бархудров*  есть такой текст:

> **Суффикс -ец.** Названия лиц с суффиксом -ец в современном русском языке распадаются на несколько словообразователь­ных разрядов:
>
> 1. Непродуктивны образования с суффиксом -ец от глагольных основ. **Слова этого типа обозначают лиц по роду занятий, по каким-нибудь действиям, определяющим их профессию и социальное поло­жение**, напр.:
>    *боре́ц (бороться), вы́ходец (выходить), гоне́ц (гнать, гоню), гребе́ц (грести, гребу), деле́ц (делать), жнец (жать, жну), косе́ц (косить),
>    купец (купить), лове́ц (ловить), певе́ц (петь, певать), писе́ц (писать),
>    продаве́ц (продавать), творе́ц (творить), торго́вец (торговать), чтец
>    (честь, про-честь, про-чту), игрец (играть) (устар., ср. «швец, и
>    жнец, и в дуду игрец»).*

Если посмотреть на слова в скобках, то всё-таки чаще они образованы от инфинитива и настоящего времени, а не от каких-то лиц и других времён.

Обратите внимание на слово: *певе́ц (петь, певать).*

Тут похожая ситуация: «петь», но «певец»; «плыть», «но пловец».

Если обратить внимание на второе слово в скобках — «певать», то можно заметить его сходство с «плавать».

> ПЕВА́ТЬ, пева́л, -ла, -ло; несов.
> Разг. Многокр. к петь.
>
> [Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой]

Хоть и написано, что разговорное, но при этом написано: многократно к «петь».

> В повести «Детство», описывая своего отца, Лев Толстой пишет: *«Он
> любил музыку, **певал**, аккомпанируя себе на фортепиано, романсы приятеля
> своего А…».* Инициал А… обозначает Алябьева, который действительно был
> дружен с Николаем Ильичом Толстым. *[[mgpu.ru](https://su.mgpu.ru/articles/muzykalnaya-gostinaya-romansy-alyabeva/)]*

«Певал» — пел многократно.

Ведь тут тот же суффикс -ва-, о котором я писал в своём ответе, обозначающий многократность. И, скорей всего, именно он остался в «певец».

Comment: @Sharon и др. коллеги, прошу вас прекратить обсуждение личных качеств и (не)сложившихся умов. Если вы пишете, что ответ неправильный, пишите сразу почему.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126384/discussion-on-answer-by-eagle---).

Answer (score 2):

Я принципиально не отвечаю на вопросы, начинающиеся с "Почему", ибо на них есть только один правильный ответ: потому, что язык так устроен.
А вот на ошибки в ваших умопостроениях могу указать.

1. Корень не *"плов"* именно потому, что  - суффикс. Корень здесь *пло/пла/плы* - с двумя ступенями чередования.
   плавать-плывун-пловец - это все однокоренные слова, во всяком случае в историческом плавне.
2. Насчет аналогий со словами *ковка, клёв*. Оговорюсь, что кров еще можно рассматривать с некоторой оговоркой, а "*слово*" - точно не из этого ряда. Так вот в словах *"клев"* и *"ковка"* звук "в" - часть корня (*"ковать", "клевать"* и другие однокоренные не дают ни малейших оснований считать "в" суффиксом).
   В отношении корня *"кров"* возможны варианты. На историческом уровне слова *"крыть" и "кровать"*, "*кровля"* - однокоренные, что и подтверждается общностью значения, этим свойством корень *"кро/кры"* похож на разбираемый *"пло/плы"*. Так что выделение корня *"кров"*  тут спорно.
   Вместо корня *"слов"* (этот корень вообще не имеет подходящего ряда для проведения сравнения, все однокоренные слова - производные от самого слова *"слово"*), можно взять *"лов" - "улов", "ловить"*... "В" - очевидная часть корня.

Comment: *«Я принципиально не отвечаю на вопросы, начинающиеся с „Почему“, ибо на них есть только один правильный ответ: потому, что язык так устроен»*. Почему у автомобиля есть фары? Потому что он так утроен или, может, потому, что есть необходимость в тёмное время суток освещать дорогу? На ответ «потому что он так устроен» можно задать вопрос: а почему он так утроен? Ведь в мире всё не случайно, у всего есть причины.

Comment: behemothus, почему я провела аналогию со словом "слово" - потому что есть слово "слыть". Этимологически, вероятно, связаны.

Comment: @Eagle Вы извините, но я комментировать это не намерен. Меня совершенно не интересует вопрос об автомобильных фарах - и тем более ваше рассуждения на эту тему.

Comment: @Nadezhda *потому что есть слово "слыть". Этимологически, вероятно, связаны.* - не могу пока ни согласиться, ни опровергнуть. Если и есть связь, то очень далекая. В таких случаях вполне возможно морфемное переразложение... Но подумаю.

Answer (score 2):

Суфикс -в- в «пловец» тут от слова «плавать».

«Плавать» — это фреквентатив от «плыть».

> **Фреквентатив** (лат. frequentativum) — форма глагола, которая указывает на повторяющееся действие. Фреквентатив может
> рассматриваться как отдельный глагол, производный от исходного. **В
> русском языке форма фреквентатива образуется с помощью суффиксов -ыва,
> -ива, -ва, -а** (слыхивать, видывать, знавать и т. п.) и воспринимается носителями как устаревшая.
>
> *[[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2)]*

---

В «плавать»:

> Корень: -пла-; **суффикс: -ва**; глагольное окончание: -ть *[[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)]*

Суффикс «-ва» образует фреквентатив от «плыть», в котором:

> **корень: -плы-**; глагольное окончание: -ть *[[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C)]*

> **ПЛА́ВАТЬ**, -аю, -аешь; прич. наст. пла́вающий; несов.
>
> 1. То же, что плыть…, с той разницей, что плавать обозначает действие **повторяющееся, совершающееся в различных
>    направлениях, а также взад и вперед**.
>
>    ```
>    Вынырнул — вижу, Ларион рядом со мной плавает. М. Горький, Исповедь. Над садами высоко и медленно плавал коршун. И. Гончаров, Обрыв. А в дни стирки густой белый пар клубился и плавал по кухне, словно туман над болотом. Голубева, Мальчик из Уржума. Солнце потухло. Плавает запах Юных берез В воздухе сладком. Фет, Солнце потухло.
>    ```
>
> *[Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой]*

---

> Суффикс -ец- в «пловец» означает:
>
> под ударением при добавлении к основе глагола или существительного
> образует существительное со значением «тот, кто занимается указанной в
> основе деятельностью»
>
> ```
> ◆ творить → творе́ц ◆ петь → певе́ц ◆ лгать → лже́ц ◆ продавать → продаве́ц ◆ бой → бое́ц
> ```
>
> *[[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%D0%B5%D1%86)]*

---

**Таким образом в «пловец»:**

- корень: -пло-
- суффикс: -в- остался от -ва-, образущего фреквентатив от «**плы**-ть».
- суффикс: -ец- зозначает «тот, кто занимается указанной в основе деятельностью».

Comment: Спасибо! Продавать- продавец. Эта пара образована так же, как пловец, и все мне объясняет. Я-то думала, что из -оу- развился -в- (плоути), поэтому и сравнивала со словом ковать, и т.п.

Comment: Прошу прощения, у меня опять появился вопрос. А почему же тогда в словах "плыву, плывет, плывущий" тоже есть суффикс "в"?  Тут уже другая причина должна быть, вероятно.  Продаю, продающий... там -j- .

Comment: @Nadezhda Честно сказать, сложный вопрос. Возможно, потому, что раньше было «плоути», и в «плыть» от него сохранилось «т»., а в «плыву» сохранилось «в». В латинском буква V использовалась в качестве буквы U. Это сродные звуки. Могла быть «в» потом стало «у» или наоборот. «Плыву» это 1-е лицо от «плыть». Но я думаю, что «пловец», это тот, кто плавает вообще, а не плывёт в данный момент. Хотя после вашего вопроса, я уже засомневался. Может кто-то ещё что-то ответит.

Comment: С пловцом-то я разобралась, но теперь меня интересует другой вопрос.) На всякий случай галочку убрала, вдруг кто-то еще что-то знает по этому поводу. Может быть, в  формах глагола "плыть" -в- взялось именно из -у- для устранения зияния гласных.  Но тогда он должен, наверное, попадать в корень. Есть еще похожее слово "слывёт".

Answer (score 0):

1. Начну с того, что в «Толковом словаре словообразовательных частиц» Т.Ф. Ефремовой есть **очень краткая и понятная информация по теме:**

(1) Суффикс ЕЦ используется при образовании существительных от глаголов для обозначения лиц, характеризуемых действием, например: борец, гребец, гонец.

(2) При этом может наблюдаться использование **основы настоящего времени в качестве мотивирующе**й: жать – жну – жнец, грести – гребу – гребец.

2. Таким образом, мы имеем:  *плыть – плыву – пловец,  также: слыть – слыву – слово.*

Вроде бы все понятно – мы не можем присоединить суффикс ЕЦ непосредственно  к корню на гласную, так как это нехарактерно для русского языка.

3. Итак, В – это **часть основы настоящего времени**. А что делать при разборе? В состав корня мы не можем включить этот формант, остается **считать его суффиксом.** Отчасти это **условное** название – ведь это не обычный словообразовательный суффикс.

Однако другого названия  для форманта В нет, но при этом пользователи  должны понимать назначение этого «суффикса» в словообразовательной цепочке.

4. В старом словаре Тихонова приводится такая схема: **плыть – пла/ва/ть – плов/ец.** И это усечение суффикса ВА, опять же **суффикс, а не корень.** Так что общепринятое мнение на данный момент: пло/в/ец. формант В  не относится к корню, а входит в основу.

**Дополнение**

1. Как образовалось "слово"? *Слово*  и *слава* – они оба существовали в древнерусском языке еще в 11 веке. А корень индоевропейский –  (k) lou – от слышать, тот же корень в словах слух.
   Но значение уже тогда было разное: ***слово*** от слыть – называться, быть известным, а ***слава*** от хвалить, вторичное значение

Словообразование: откуда взялся суффикс В?  Только от такой цепочки: Слыть – слыву –  слово, и это **общая закономерность языка**, а не такой частный пример, как в *плыть – плавать – пловец.*

Кстати, почему мы тогда не пишем **«плавец»**, всё бы исключений было поменьше.  В словаре, пловец – это «умеющий плавать» и  «плывущий».
Скорее здесь такая перегласовка: плыть – плыву – пл(Ы/О)вец.

2. Другие слова: *Жать – жнец*, откуда там Н?  Всё по той же причине: *жать – жну – жнец,  грести – гребу – гребец*, за ответом далеко ходить не надо.

Решение общее для всего класса подобных слов, и его можно изложить в двух предложениях, а не на двух листах.

Comment: Спасибо! Кстати, в паре жить - жилец тоже появляется загадочный звук -л-, очевидно, для той же цели, формант, выделяемый как суффикс. В цепочке плыть - плыву - пловец есть то, что удивляет: -плыв- , по-моему, логично считать полностью корнем, тогда и в слове пловец стоило бы оставить -в- в корне. Поэтому мне больше нравится мысль, что -в- - это усечение от -ва-. Как в продавать - продавец.

Comment: Я как раз пишу в дополнении, что В - это часть основы "плыву", такие форманты-надставки не редкость в языке, а закономерность. А если бы не было формы плавать? Все рано мы писали бы пловец, нам нужен этот формант. Да и в слове плавать ВА - это суффикс, а не часть корня. Жить - жил - жилец, Здесь заимствуем Л (суффикс прошедшего времени).

Comment: Жать - жну - жнец - я думаю ,что там -н- от носового, скорее всего там был юс, поэтому это другая история. Да и гребец - вероятно, было изначально в н.ф. гребсти, и -б- исчезло со временем, а не появилось в "гребец".  Кстати, вспомнила еще слово "живец" - ловить на живца. Я пока думаю.) спасибо за Ваши рассуждения.