# О термине «фрекентатив» при разборе слова "плавать" по составу

Tags: терминология, морфемный-разбор

**Цитата из ответа:** Таким образом в слове «пловец» суффикс: -в- остался от -ва-, образующего **фрекентатив** от «плы-ть». [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/466692/Суффиксы-](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/466692/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%8B-)

1. **Фрекентатив** – это специальный лингвистический термин, актуальный в сравнительном языкознании.

Википедия:  **Фреквентатив** – форма глагола , которая указывает на **повторяющееся** действие. Фреквентатив может рассматриваться как отдельный глагол, производный от исходного. Фреквентатив также есть в некоторых других языках, таких как латинский , балто-славянские ( польский , литовский ), финно-угорские ( финский , венгерский ), тюркские и т. д.

2. Применять его в школьном разборе слов по составу вроде бы нет особой необходимости, его значение указывается только в специальных словарях
3. Но есть еще термин **«итератив»**, он обозначен в общих словарях:

**Итератив** (от лат. iterare — вторично делать, повторять; также многократный вид) — вид глагола, обозначающий **многократное или повторяющееся** действие.

4. В русском языке форма фреквентатива образуется с помощью суффиксов -ыва , -ива, -ва, -а (***слышивать, видывать, знавать*** и т.п.) и воспринимается носителями **как устаревшая.**

Как-то не очень похоже на ***плавать***.

5. И вопрос: **Так плавать – это фрекентатив или итератив?**

Корректно ли применять **подобные термины** в школьной практике? Стоит ли учащимся отвлекаться  на подобную терминологию или лучше больше внимания уделять вопросам по существу?

Comment: *“Корректно ли применять подобные термины в школьной практике? Стоит ли учащимся отвлекаться на подобную терминологию или лучше больше внимания уделять вопросам по существу?”* Я что-то не понял, мы в школе сейчас находимся? Мы школьников учим? Давайте зададимся теперь вопросом, а корректно ли применять этот термин в детском саду? А в яслях? А в роддоме?

Answer (score 1):

Погуглила. Хотя при исследовании "глагольной множественности", Дресслер, 1968, выделяет в своей работе различные итеративные нюансы, и среди них есть фреквентатив. Храковский 1989, так определяет «фреквантатив» как **частный случай** - «итератив с малыми интервалами между повторяющимися ситуациями», в целом их можно рассматривать как синонимичные и часто взаимозаменяемые.
Особенно если мы не диссертацию пишем, а ищем, как объяснить школьникам, что -в- в слове пловец - суффикс, а не часть корня. Для чего это делать? Дала трем школьникам разобрать это слово - все выделяют корень плов, все удивляются, что -в- является отдельной морфемой и просят объяснений. Они перебирают в уме родственные слова, связанные с этим словом - и им кажется, что общая часть включает этот звук. Плавать, пловец, плывущий, плывет, заплыв и т.п. Когда они в 5 или 6 классе изучают чередование в корнях, им предлагают эти корни под  видом "плав/плыв". Вот цитата с сайта Грамота.ру: "1. От места ударения в слове зависит написание корней ГОР/ГАР, КЛОН/КЛАН, ТВОР/ТВАР, **ПЛОВ/ПЛАВ**, ЗOР/ЗАР." Когда детям объясняешь причину  такого деления на морфемы, они начинают еще больше интересоваться русским языком, а когда говоришь, что они должны просто запомнить, потому что в словарях именно такой разбор, "исторически так сложилось", дети теряют интерес и не пытаются ни в чем самостоятельно разбираться. Для них это и есть вопрос по существу.

Comment: (1) Итак,  фреквентатив –  это частный случай итератива,  а именно итератив с малыми интервалами между повторяющимися ситуациями. Итератив хотя бы на слух хорошо знаком, его в обычных словарях можно найти. Неужели нам еще частный случай надо использовать. Да и характеристика у него сомнительная: «слышивать»  как-то мало похоже  на  «плавать».  Поэтому можно предположить, что плавать – это скорее обычный  «итератив».

Comment: (2) Наша система преподавания знаний в готовом виде всегда вызывала критику – решать задачи интереснее, чем заучивать правила, я об этом здесь часто говорю. Я считаю, что каждое привило и каждое исключение должно иметь объяснение.  Я, к примеру,  могу объяснить любое правило, а вы? Дети учат корни ПЛАВ/ПЛОВ для правописания, там не стоит говорить иначе. Но при изучении словообразования  эта приблизительная  версия уже не подходит – такие нюансы тоже надо объяснять.

Comment: (3) Много малоизученных проблем в школе, вот и не надо перегружать ее научными терминами. Терминология – это как стили речи, для школы – одна, для вузов – другая, а для научной работы – третья. Здесь тоже свои правила использования терминов.

Comment: Насчет " фреквентатив – это частный случай итератива, а именно итератив с малыми интервалами между повторяющимися ситуациями " - не совсем, поспешный вывод, в той диссертации все эти термины взяты в кавычки, с оговоркой в сноске, что они часто "материально" совпадают в разных работах, но при этом под ними подразумевается порой не тождественное, а  противоположное значение.

Answer (score 1):

> In grammar, a frequentative form (abbreviated freq or fr) of a word is
> one that indicates repeated action, but is not to be confused with
> iterative aspect.
>
> В грамматике фреквентативная форма… слова – это форма, которая
> указывает на повторяющееся действие, но её не следует путать с
> итеративным видом.
>
> [ [wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequentative) ]

> The iterative aspect (abbreviated iter), also called
> “semelfactive”, “event-internal pluractionality”, or
> “multiplicative”, is a grammatical aspect that expresses the
> repetition of an event observable on one single occasion, as in ‘he
> knocked on the door’, ‘he coughed’, ‘she is drumming’, etc. It
> is not to be confused with frequentative aspect and habitual aspect,
> which both signal repetition over more than one occasion.
>
> Итеративный вид…, также называемый «полуактивным», «внутренней
> множественностью события» или «мультипликативным», представляет собой
> грамматический вид, который выражает **повторение события,
> наблюдаемого в одном единственном случае**, например, «он постучал по
> дверь», «он закашлялся», «она барабанит» и т. д. Его не следует путать
> с фреквентативным и хабитуальным видами, которые оба указывают на
> повторение более чем однин раз.
>
> [[wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_aspect)]

Таким образом итератив в отличие от фрекфентатива – это повторение наблюдаемое в одном единственном случае.

«Он стучит в дверь» – можно рассматривать как итератив, потому что это повторение действия в одном случае, фактически это одно действие состоящее из повторяющихся действий (внутренняя множественность событий).

А пловец плавает не в данный момент, а плавает вообще периодически, такой у него род занятий.

Comment: @Nadezhda Прочитайте мой ответ, может вам будет интересно.

Comment: @  Eagle.  Уважаемый пользователь. Пожалуйста, используйте в ответе  авторитетные русскоязычные источники по грамматике. Мы изучаем не английскую, а русскую грамматику. Как частотность применения терминов, так и их значение могут быть разными.

Comment: @Sharon Уважаемый критик. Подавляющее большинство терминов русской грамматики являются иноязычными заимствованиями или кальками иностранных терминов. Я привел международные определения, которые касаются не только английского языка. В англоязычной статье по фреквентативу рассматриваются: финский, греческий, венгерский, латинский, литовский, польский и русский языки. Есть много общих явлений в разных языках и о них можно говорить использую единую терминологию.

Comment: Меня интересует русская грамматика, а не общее языкознание. Приведите цитаты из русских источников, где для них даются определения русским текстом. Русская грамматика-80, Корпусная грамматика, учебники для вузов, научные статьи и т.д.  Также нужно видеть область применения этих терминов.